# How to run a function on each element in a list in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, list, functional-programming, java-stream

I would like to know if it's possible to use streams to call a function on each element in a list and to ***modify*** its value as well.

Let's say I have a list of integers: `List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);`

And a method that increments every number by one:

```
public static Integer plusOne(Integer n){
    return n + 1;
}
```

This is what I used to call the function on each element and modify the original list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    list.set(i, plusOne(list.get(i)));
}
```

However, I wanted to know if there is a shorter way of writing this using streams?

I tried using:

```
list.stream()
    .forEach(e -> plusOne(e));
```

But it doesn't seem to change the original list, nor return anything... If it's impossible to change the original list using streams, how can I at least get a new modified copy of the list?

The output, by the way, should be a list of (2,3,4) after calling the function on the list.

Comment: Use `map` instead

Comment: Mutating the collection you're iterating through streams seems like a very bad idea to start with. You're likely better of generating a new `List` with the updated values.

Comment: One of the many benefits of streams, is that it discourages mutating data structures.

Answer (score 3):

No need for a Stream.  You can just use [List.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-):

```
list.replaceAll(MyApplication::plusOne);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `map` with `collect` as `stream` alone does not modify the existing list, e.g.:

```
public static int plusOne(int i){
    return i + 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
    List<Integer> updated = list.stream()
            .map(i -> plusOne(i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(updated);
}
```

Or even,

```
List<Integer> updated = list.stream()
            .map(i -> i + 1)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(updated);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Darshan Mehta!

Answer (score 1):

You can mutate your `List` while streaming it through the following idiom.

Note that this is **absolutely horrible code**, and constitutes a **horrible practice** altogether.

Only for experimenting.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
// cannot have a re-assignable index here as it requires being effectively final
int[] i = {0};
// iterating list
list.forEach(
    // for each element...
    (e) -> 
    // setting list at current index and incrementing index, with current value + 1
    list.set(i[0]++, e + 1)
);
System.out.println(list);
```

**Output**

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

**Notes**

- This will work with the above idiom because there is no parallel processing of the stream, and the indexing array container is mutated predictably.
- The recommended practice is to generate a new `List` by streaming, mapping the values to their increment and collecting as `List` (see second part of [Darshan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120793/darshan-mehta)'s answer for a trivial example)

Comment: Thank you very much Mena! I wanted to ask about the `i[0]++` part, I've never seen usage of indexes like this before, do you know where I can find information about this way and why a normal int doesn't work?

Comment: @Engineer you're welcome. What's happening with the array-based indexing (as opposed to a simple `int`) is that within the lambda, variables from the local scope of the method (amongst others) must be effectively `final` to be referenced. However, you cannot re-assign a `final int` multiple times obviously. But you *can* mutate an `int[]`. Or an `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: @Engineer note that the above is closer to a "parlor trick" than to a common practice, another red flag for the solution I've shown you - never use that in production!

Answer (score 1):

Although there are ways to modify the input list as you go, we have learned to avoid doing so, because it causes problems.

You can replace the existing list (in the current scope) with the new list, pretty easily:

```
 list = list.stream().map(...).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is nice and clean. Your old list still exists (until potential garbage-collection). Any other references to it see no change -- which is healthy. If there are no more references to it, it's garbage-collected.

Comment: Thank you very much Slim! So you're saying that Streams were created for the very purpose of _not_ having to modify original objects' values?

Comment: Well, you never *had* to modify original objects' values. But streams encourage code in which you don't.